# Date equal to max date is not working in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I need to model below query in tableau.

```
Select * from table where date = (Select max(Date) from table);
```

I have created a calculated field to filter data as below but its not working. I am selecting only true table.

```
max(Date)== Total(Max(Date))
```

Please suggest on the above.

Answer (score 1):

Issue resolved by below calculated field:

```
{FIXED:MAX(Date)}
```